# ¿Como filtrar los registros de mongodb por meses y año usando mongoose?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Como puedo realizar una consulta en mongodb usando mongoose, express y nodejs donde me filtre los registros por meses y año,
Este es mi constructor:

```
 list: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const reg = await models.BitacoraEmbarcacion.find(?)
        .populate("agencia")
        .populate("embarcacion")
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
      res.status(200).json(reg);
    } catch (e) { 
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Ocurrio un error",
      });
      next(e);
    }
  },
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose';

const bitacoraEmbarcacionSchema = new Schema({
    agencia: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'agencia', required:true},
    embarcacion: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'embarcacion', required:true},
    atraque: {type:Date, required:true},
    desatraque: {type:Date, required:true},
    estadia: {type:Number, required:true},
    embarquePx: {type:Number, required:true},
    desembarquePx: {type:Number, required:true},
    folioServicio : {type:String,required:true},
    entrada: {type:Number,required:true},
    salida: {type:Number,required:true}
})

const bitacoraEmbarcacion = mongoose.model('bitacoraEmbarcacion',bitacoraEmbarcacionSchema);
export default bitacoraEmbarcacion
```

Quiero filtrar por meses y año el campo **desatraque**

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Intente con .populate pero no me funciona